# Local Date Parsing 2021-06-07+03:00

Tags: java, spring, localdate

How can I parse this code to  localDate?

DateTimeParseException: Text '2021-06-07+03:00' could not be parsed at index 10

I have tried both DateTimeFormatter.ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME and DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd"). these are not work.

Do u you have any suggestions?

Comment: "DateTimeFormatter java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE - 
The ISO date formatter that formats or parses a date with the offset if available, such as '2011-12-03' or '2011-12-03+01:00'."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be something like this?

```
String dt="2021-06-07+03:00";
DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter= DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE;
System.out.println(dateTimeFormatter.parse(dt).get(ChronoField.OFFSET_SECONDS));
System.out.println(dateTimeFormatter.parse(dt).get(ChronoField.DAY_OF_YEAR));
```

Output:

```
Offset seconds: 10800
Day of year:158
```

Comment: The question specifically asks about a `LocalDate` (in its title)… Could you change the code to one that produces an instance of `LocalDate`?

Comment: sure @deHaar, thank you for suggestion, will have a look & change accordingly.
Edit : i think OP's requirement matches with original answer, so will keep it as it is. Thanks again.

Comment: Actually, I ask for LocalDate not for LocalDateTime.I adapt it for my code. Thank you.